# How many photons are used to make one glucose?

Tags: plant-physiology, photosynthesis

This was a question in a test. The options were

(1) 8

(2) 16

(3) 24

(4) 48

My answer is 30 which was not in options.  Given answer was 48.

12 NADPH
18 ATP for one glucose

12 NADPH and ATP from z scheme where 24 photons are used.

6 ATP more from cyclic where 6 photons are used.

Net 30.

Can someone point out an argument against this?

One explanation for 48 is:

2 electron each hydrogen atom

4 electrons per water molecule

2 water molecules for one oxygen molecule

8 electrons=8 photons for each oxygen,

each glucose 6 oxygen so 8×6 = 48

But what is the mistake in argument for 30?